# Text input placeholders and cross browser support

Tags: jquery, placeholder

So I'm aware that the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute isn't supported in IE before IE10, but I really need the functionality.

I thought I could do the following, but it doesn't seem to work (looks like the `.focus` and `.blur` methods aren't being fired...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {

        function isPlaceholderSupported() {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            return ('placeholder' in input);
        }

        var placeholderSupport = isPlaceholderSupported();

        if (placeholderSupport == false) {
            $('#store_name').val('Store Name');
        }

        $('#store_name').focus(function() {
            if (placeholderSupport == false) {
                if ($(this).val() == 'Store Name') {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            }
        });

        $('#store_name').blur(function() {
            if (placeholderSupport == false) {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).val('Store Name');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="store_name" id="store_name" placeholder="Store Name" />
```

I can't see any flaw in the logic here, but this just isn't working. There's no errors being reported in Chrome's dev tools and I haven't tried it in IE9 yet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are various [existing `placeholder` polyfills (this one is written by me)](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) that you may want to consider using.

Comment: I'll have a look, but I want to avoid using too many different script references and stuff

Comment: If you want to write your own, you may want to consider things like the fact that your current version will cause the placeholder text to be submitted along with the form if the user doesn't change the value.

Comment: That's fine because while these default values are set, the form won't submit anyway, but I'm still stuck with the problem that the focus/blur events don't seem to be firing

Comment: What you have [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/qgpFd/). I think your problem is likely to be elsewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check jQuery below only for IE

```
    $(function() {
       var textBox = $('input[type="text"]');
       textBox.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.val(self.attr('placeholder'));
       });
    });
    $(document).on('focus', textBox, function() {
        var self = $(this);
       if(self.val() == self.attr('placeholder')) {
           self.val('');
       }
    });
    $(document).on('blur', textBox, function() {
        var self = $(this);
        if(self.val() == '') {
            self.val(self.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="email" type="text"/>

 /*placeholder*/
function initPlaceHolder(input, defaultValue) {
    input.onfocus = function() {
                    if (input.value == defaultValue){
                      input.value = "";
                      input.style.color = '#444444';
                    }
                  };

    function remove() {
        if (input.value == "") {
          input.value = defaultValue;
          input.style.color = '#c9c9c9';              
        }
    }
    input.onblur = remove;
    remove();
}
window.onload = function(){
    initPlaceHolder(document.getElementById("email"), "Enter your Email");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*For placeholder*/ 
function ClearPlaceHolder(input) {      
    if (input.value == input.defaultValue){
        input.value = "";
        document.getElementById(input.id).style.color = '#444444';
    }
}

function SetPlaceHolder (input) {
   if (input.value == "") {
        input.value = input.defaultValue;
        document.getElementById(input.id).style.color = '#c9c9c9';              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an existing plugin like http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-watermark?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(function() {
var input = document.createElement("input");
if(('placeholder' in input)==false) { 
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
        var i = $(this);
        if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
            i.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
            if(i.hasClass('password')) {
                i.removeClass('password');
                this.type='password';
            }           
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var i = $(this);    
        if(i.val() == '' || i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
            if(this.type=='password') {
                i.addClass('password');
                this.type='text';
            }
            i.addClass('placeholder').val(i.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var i = $(this);
            if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
                i.val('');
        })
    });
}
});
/* ]]> */
```

Try this one..

Comment: it supports input type password. IE7>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for Placeholders supporting IE9+

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if(input.attr('data-password') == 'password') {
        input.attr('type','password');
        input.attr('data-password','text');
    }
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
        if(input.attr('type') == 'password') {
            input.attr('type','text');
            input.attr('data-password','password');
        }
    }
}).blur(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if(input.attr('data-password') == 'password') {
        input.attr('type','password');
        input.attr('data-password','text');
    }
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        if(input.attr('type') == 'password') {
            input.attr('type','text');
            input.attr('data-password','password');
        }
    }
}).keyup(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if(input.attr('data-password') == 'password') {
        input.attr('type','password');
        input.attr('data-password','text');
    }
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        if(input.attr('type') == 'password') {
            input.attr('type','text');
            input.attr('data-password','password');
        }
    }
}).blur();
```